# CentOS use SNMP to show interface useage

Tags: linux, centos, snmp, redhat, cacti

I have an SNMP monitoring box and want to monitor interface utilisation on a clustered database server. I'm trying to work out the correct OID to monitor - I just need SNMP to return the total interface throughput at a given time.

The SNMP box is already configured and will correctly graph it. All howtos I can find talk about setting up Catci or MRTG which is all well and good, but what I need seems simpler, yet I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. The SNMP box is already configured with the correct community name etc so this should be a really easy one in theory.

Any help very gratefully received

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When you say "interface utilisation", I assume you mean Ethernet interface utilization.  If that assumption is correct, there are a couple OIDs to investigate:

- `1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10` - [ifInOctets](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10) returns the total number of octets received on the interface, including framing characters.
- `1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16` - [ifOutOctets](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16) returns the total number of octets transmitted out of the interface, including framing characters.
- `1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6` - [ifHCInOctets](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6) returns the total number of octets received on the interface, including framing characters (this is the 64-bit version of ifInOctets).
- `1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.10` - [ifHCInOctets](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.10) returns the total number of octets transmitted out of the interface, including framing characters (this is the 64-bit version of ifOutOctets).

Each OID is part of a table and will have an associated index that links it to an interface description (e.g., `eth0` or `br1`).

These OIDs provide a count of octets received and transmitted so they require a little massaging to get into the utilization rates you desire.  In the past when I've monitored these OIDs I've queried for two values a few seconds apart and then calculated the rate.

```
(QueryResult2 - QueryResult1) / (SecondsElapsed)
```

I would guess that Cacti (which I assume you're using since you tagged your question with it) has some way to calculate rates from SNMP values, however, I've never used it so I am not positive.

One other important note is that the default *snmpd.conf* included with CentOS may not have these OIDs enabled.  If you run `snmpwalk` on `1.3.6.1.2.1.2` and `1.3.6.1.2.1.31` and receive empty results, edit `/etc/snmpd.conf` to configure the SNMP daemon to respond to those OIDs.  I can't remember the exact syntax but I think adding a line like,

```
view   all   included   .1
```

will enable all available OIDs on the server.

Comment: Thanks for that comment, you're right I do mean Ethernet interface utilisation. I ran snmpwalk and got the following output: `[root@node1 ~]# snmpwalk -v 1 -c public localhost ifSpeed
IF-MIB::ifSpeed.1 = Gauge32: 10000000
IF-MIB::ifSpeed.2 = Gauge32: 10000000
IF-MIB::ifSpeed.3 = Gauge32: 1000000000
IF-MIB::ifSpeed.4 = Gauge32: 1000000000
IF-MIB::ifSpeed.5 = Gauge32: 1000000000
IF-MIB::ifSpeed.6 = Gauge32: 10000000
IF-MIB::ifSpeed.7 = Gauge32: 0
`

Comment: Sorry meant to say, that looks to be giving me the link speed (i.e. 10mbps/100mbps/gig etc) rather than interface utilisation?

Comment: @btongeorge You're right!  I didn't have a box handy to test the OIDs to verify that I was giving you correct information.  Sorry to lead you down the wrong path.

Comment: @btongeorge I've revised my answer to something that I've actually used in the past with success.  I hope it helps!

Comment: no problem at all, thanks for the additional info. I was hoping for an SNMP OID that would do the massaging for me, but will see what I can do with octets in and out.

Answer (score 0):

here is my small script for that :
[enter link description here](https://github.com/NessYou-cyber/bandwidth/blob/main/bandwidth.sh)
result :
Interface bandwidth usage: In: 22837768 bps, Out: 5202640 bps

Answer (score -2):

http://namhuy.net/908/how-to-install-iftop-bandwidth-monitoring-tool-in-rhel-centos-fedora.html

Requirements:
libpcap: module provides a user-level network packet capture information and statistics.
libncurses: is a API programming library that enables programmers to provide text-based interfaces in a terminal.
gcc: GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) is a compiler system produced by the GNU Project supporting various programming languages.

Install libpcap, libnurses, gcc via yum

```
yum -y install libpcap libpcap-devel ncurses ncurses-devel gcc
```

Download and Install iftop

```
wget http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/download/iftop-0.17.tar.gz
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: Why did this get down voted? Looks to solve my problem without having to do maths on the resulting SNMP queries.